# Change the scaling value in print box dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i change automaticaly the scaling value from 100 (default) to 60 in the print box dialog of Google Chrome from Javascript or Css ?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: This looks like a print menu from Chrome/Chromium. If that is the case, then as far as I know, Chrome does not provide a JS based API to manage these settings. You can see their extensions developer page to find out.